# what does this line mean in ruby var1 = "" if self.title.match(/(#{var1})/i)

Tags: ruby

I am php developer, converting ruby script to PHP, I couldn't find this syntax anywhere. Please help me understand what it means.

```
var1 = "" if self.title.match(/(#{var1})/i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that it should return an empty string `""` if `self.title` matches the regular expression that gets interpolated by `#{var1}`, the `/i` means it's case insensitive.

Comment: Where exactly is it ternary? "Shortened ternary" is binary. Otherwise, `return 0` is a shortened ternary, too (we got rid of that `if`, `then` and `else` altogether. Shortened radically) :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,

```
greeting = "Hello"
puts "#{greeting} world"

--output:--
Hello world
```

So the #{..} construct allows you to interpolate variables into strings--it's more verbose than php's $variable interpolation into strings, but that's the way it goes.  In ruby, you can also interpolate arbitrary expressions into strings:

```
puts "1 + 2 = #{1+2}"

--output:--
1 + 2 = 3


def get_greeting
  "Goodbye"
end

puts "#{get_greeting} world"

--output:--
Goodbye world
```

Here's your example:

```
title = "HELLO"
var1 = "hello"

var1 = "" if title.match(/(#{var1})/i)
puts "--->#{var1}<--"

--output:--
---><--
```

...which is equivalent to:

```
title = "HELLO"
var1 = "hello"

if title.match(/(#{var1})/i)
  var1 = ""
end

puts "--->#{var1}<--"

--output:--
---><--
```

...which is equivalent to:

```
title = "HELLO"
var1 = "hello"

if title.match(/(hello)/i)
  var1 = ""
end

puts "--->#{var1}<--"

--output:--
---><--
```

Note that you can use the #{...} construct to interpolate a variable into a regex.